# z shell issue, running an alias and getting this " zsh: parse error near `}' "

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, command-line, alias, zsh

I'm trying to make an alias in `z shell (5.5.1)` that will write `node.js` server code to a file, `app.js`. When I run the alias I get this

> "zsh: parse error near `}'"

I tried to escape the curly brackets, that didn't work. I've searched and searched but couldn't find anything to clarify what I am doing wrong.

```
alias srvr='echo const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("vendors"));

 app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
 });

 app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!");
 });' > app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing after the unquoted semicolon is treated as an argument to `echo`. You should not be using an alias for this anyway. Use a function instead.

```
srvr () {
    echo 'const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("vendors"));

 app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
 });

 app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!");
 });' > app.js
}
```

Comment: The hideously long single-quoted string is still hard to read and slightly error-prone (easy to accidentally edit in something with single quotes in it). Perhaps use a here-document instead?